# How can I detect and correct these errors on my blog?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, blogs, adsense

My blog is valcun.com and I am trying to get adsense approved on it. I have applied twice but both times google has rejected saying that my blog doesn't adhere to Google policies. The reason is not clear. So I am confused. I write original content that is copyscape-pass and nothing is offensive. Its a clean technical blog for layman.

I played with google analytics and found these issues. What is wrong with my blog and why is Google not approving Adsense? It's been 6 months now.

I submit site map to google, yahoo, etc regularly from my cPanel in hostgator site. I have the robot.txt file. I am at a loss to understand what's wrong with my blog that google won't approve! I have seen blogs less than a month old and with Adsense! How so? I do on-page seo in my articles and I submit my articles in article directories too. So why google doesn't want to approve Adsense for my blog?

I am assuming that it's because of the following errors that my blog isn't getting approval. Is that so? How can I correct these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Edit 1

@Secret: Yes I am using Yoast currently. I have also tried All in One SEO. And those duplicate meta description entries are showing like only my blog's title. I mean how can I correct that error. I am unable to understand what to change and how.

Also, I am concentrating more on google organic search traffic and avoiding any kind of referral traffic because I read somewhere that organic traffic needs to be at least 50%. I checked today and search traffic has reached 50% now, if I see total of 6 months. Still Google won't approve.

Apart from the errors above, webmaster tools is also showing the following sitemap error which I can't understand.

[image]

### Edit 2

I had 2 SEO plugins on my blog and I would put meta description for each of my article in both plugins that are All in One SEO and Yoast's "Wordpress SEO". Now I removed all article's meta descriptions from "All in one SEO" the other day but STILL web master tool is showing duplicate meta tags and descriptions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you must submit a XML sitemap to google. create one here 

 http://http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ and upload it to google and varify

Comment: @Hareesh: Site map problem is resolved now..only thing left is this duplicate description issues..

Comment: post you header.php code, may be some coding error.

Comment: I took a look at your source code and it seems that you've used the same metatag 3 times on your pages, Google probably doesn't like this. The problem could be that using more than one SEO plugin has duplicated it. Also the metatag descriptions are very long. Furthermore the titles you have used are not very clean, the title for your homepage looks more like a list of keywords. Other titles are incomplete. I think all the issues are with the titles and metatagging, I would go back and start again on both those aspects, making sure they conform to logical sense, and say what the page is about.

Answer (score 1):

The report does say there are duplicate meta descriptions, and short meta descriptions, so it would help if you improve them. And from what I can see, you are using Wordpress. Have you tried using any SEO plugins?

Comment: Yes I am using Yoast currently. I have also tried All in One SEO. And those duplicate meta description entries are showing like only my blog's title. I mean how can I correct that error. I am unable to understand what to change and how.

Comment: same meta 'description' and meta 'keywords' sometimes have negative effects. Maybe that's what's triggering the red flag

Comment: okk...can you please have a look at my blog and tell me how can I correct this? Its showing the Blog's title as duplicate. I don't understand how to correct this error.

Comment: seems to me that All in one SEO is still activated, creating two metas (along with Yoast). Look at one of your posts to see what I mean. Also, YOast seems to have a problem too with duplicate title tags

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with the positioning of the ads on your website. [Google's Adsense policy](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23921) says to:

> Maintain adequate space between the ads and the page controls.

It isn't clear exactly what Google means by "page controls" but they might consider your website's primary navigation a "page control" and this might be one of the reasons why you have been rejected.

Also from Google's Adsense policy:

> Make sure that your ads are well-placed on your site, away from
>   interactive elements, do not mimic the surrounding content and are not
>   placed under misleading headings.

The Google Ad block on the right of your website might ["blend in"](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1346295#Formatting_content_to_mimic_ads) with the other content on your page too much.

So where can you put them? Well, I have had success with having an ad block in the middle or at the end of the content in an individual blog post. So I would suggest removing the ads from where you have them now, placing them where I have suggest, and reapplying. If you're still rejected at least you can cross this off of your list.

Answer (score 1):

> Meta description tags, while not important to search engine rankings,
>   are extremely important in gaining user click-through from search
>   engine result pages (SERPs). These short paragraphs are webmasters
>   opportunity to advertise content to searchers and let them know
>   exactly what the given page has with regard to what they’re looking
>   for. The meta description should employ the keywords intelligently,
>   but also create a compelling description that a searcher will want to
>   click. Direct relevance to the page and uniqueness between each page’s
>   meta description is key. The description should optimally be between
>   150-160 characters. *

From [SEOMOZ](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/meta-description)

You should let either Yoast or All in one do the meta tags. You said you were using both at one time, maybe you didn't remove them once you were done using one of them.

Try [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) to help you identify which of your pages are considered duplicates and sort them out.